# Execute Pre-Compiled Bundled Program with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appkit

I'm trying to build an app which uses a CLI tool for a lot of the work, and I'm wondering if it is possible to bundle and execute a pre-compiled tool from Swift in XCode on macOS 10.15+? I can add the binary to the bundle however the file is read-only and cannot be executed.

#### Example

There should be a binary called `cli` available in the bundle.

```swift
let stdOut = Pipe()
let process = Process()
process.executableURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cli", withExtension: "")!
process.arguments = args
process.standardOutput = stdOut
try! process.run()
```

#### Error

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “cli” doesn’t exist."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The error you are seeing is most likely caused by the missing executable permission on the `cli` binary.

Can you make sure the file is actually executable? You can just run `ls -lh cli` on the file. The output should look like this.

```
ls -lh cli 
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  staff    36K 28 Mai 02:24 cli
```

If your output is missing the `x`, then the file is missing executable permissions. You can add those to the file using `chmod +x cli`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yeah it seems I was getting a bad error, it could find the file  was there but permissions weren't set on the original.